# Metadata not saving when uploading a file through Google Cloud functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, metadata

I am resizing an image using firebase cloud function and would like to set custom metadata.

I copied the code straight from  [google's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions)

However, when I re-read the file, it has no metadata set at all.

```
export const generateThumbs = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async object => {
  const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
  const filePath = object.name as string; // File path in the bucket.
  const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.

  const metadata: any = object.metadata || {};

  // First time around this works and logs metadata.
  // I set "isThumb" as false on client. It is set in 
  // the first run!
  // In the second run, it comes back as undefined
  console.log(object.metadata);

  if (metadata && metadata.isThumb) {
    console.log("Already a thumbnail");
    return;
  }
// .... later
metadata.isThumb = true;

  // Override the original file with the smaller one
  // I am passing it the same metadata, and yet 
  // when the function is triggered again, the 
  // metadata is undefined!  This part is straight from
  // google's documentation. 
  await bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {
    destination: filePath,
    metadata: metadata
  });
```

I expect metadata to be set, but it comes back as undefined.

Comment: What is the output from `console.log(contentType )`?

Comment: In the first-run, metadata.  In the second-run, 'undefined'.

Comment: According to the document customMetadata in the section Get file metadata  you should use the getMetadata() method to get the metadata,neither I see that you use the method updateMetadata() to update the file metadata.

Comment: I copied my code straight from google's documentation. The link is in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. It has to be:

await bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {
    destination: filePath,
    metadata: { metadata: metadata }
  });

Google's documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions doesn't mention that.

Comment: This is true and ridiculously so.

Comment: This still is the case.

Comment: Sadly this type of thing is a reoccurring theme in the google storage JavaScript APIs